# problem with angularJS and javascript button switching

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a button for each component of a list, when this button is clicked I want to exchange it for another button I am using angularJS ng-click when I click the first time this button is changed in the other attempts only when I reload the page, follow the source code

```
<button id='btn' type="button" class='btn btn-primary justify-content-between align-items-xl-center'
        ng-click="vcl.Participantes = vcl.Participantes + 1;
                  participarDoSorteio(this);"
        ng-init="count=vcl.Participantes">
  Participar
</button>
```

Controller:

```
adicionarInfos.then(function(d) {
  //if (d.status === 201) {
  document.getElementById("btn").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("part").style.display = 'block';
  //}
});
```

Comment: You should not use 'document.getElementById'. There is no reason for that

Comment: Use the `ng-if` directive to add/remove buttons. Or `ng-show/ng-hide` to show/hide buttons.

Comment: I am already using ng-if when reloading the page the problem is that I want to change the button after the click